# Strange behaviour with recycle View

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to add a item to my recycle View, but something really strange is happening, when my keyboard is up and i write on him the name of the item to insert the item doesn't appear on the recycle view BEFORE i close the keyboard, even if i write the name of the item close the keyboard and then click add it never shows on the list, i don't know if it has something to do with my recycle view xml, maybe i need to configure something there, so here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager.Friends">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleUsers"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Contact list "
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="298dp"
        android:onClick="addFriend"
        android:text="Add"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/number"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Tipe a number "
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/recycleUsers" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: did you try to close keyboard manually ???? for example when click add button or enter key ... you can do this in java ! try that

Comment: i solved it, the problem was not with the keyboard, the problem was that i forgot the mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();